# Como puedo restar un valor por cada fila con PHP

Tags: php

muy buenas noches.

Tengo el siguiente código:

almacen.php

En este archivo tengo un formulario el cual se sube un archivo en excel con las variables de cliente, codigo (este es el código de cada producto) cantidad_restar(esta es la cantidad que estoy buscando restar).

```
<form action="iexcesin.php" method="post" name="frmExcelImport" id="frmExcelImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type="text" name="cliente" value="<?php echo $acliente?>" readonly="readonly">

<input type="file" name="file" required />
<label for="file-1">
<span>Seleccionar archivo</span>
</label>
      

<br>                
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="import" value="SINCRONIZAR">
</center>
</form>
```

Este es el archivo que procesa la información:
iexcesin.php

Actualmente en este archivo recibo las variables y se insertan en la base de datos. Lo que estoy buscando hacer es que al momento de subir el archivo en excel con el código este pueda comparar en la tabla recibir_items variable código que sea igual al que estoy subiendo y restarle la cantidad que viene en la variable cantidad_restar.

Solo que esto se debe hacer por cada producto que este en el archivo excel.

```
<?php
include('dbconect.php');
require_once('vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

$acliente = !empty($_REQUEST['cliente']) ? $_REQUEST['cliente'] : '';

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{
    
$allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
  
  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'subidas/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
        
        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {
            
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
            
            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {
                
                $cliente = "";
                if(isset($Row[0])) {
                    $cliente = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[0]);
                }
          
                $codigo = "";
                if(isset($Row[1])) {
                    $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[1]);
                }
                
                
                $cantidad_restar = "";
                if(isset($Row[5])) {
                    $cantidad_restar = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Row[5]);
                }
                
                
                if (!empty($codigo) || !empty($cantidad_restar)) {
                    $query = "insert into recibir_items(cliente, codigo, cantidad_restar) values ('".$acliente."','".$codigo."','".$cantidad_restar."')";
                    $resultados = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    
                
        
                
                    if (! empty($resultados)) {
                        echo "<script>alert('Productos descontados correctamente!')
                         window.location='almacen.php';</script>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<script>alert('Ocurrió un problema al descontar productos!')
                             window.location='almacen.php';</script>";
                    }
                }
             }
        
         }
  }
  else
  { 
        echo "<script>alert('El archivo enviado es invalido. Por favor vuelva a intentarlo!')
              window.location='almacen.php';</script>";
  }
}
?>
```

No tengo una idea muy clara de como podría hacer esto, pero he estado pensando en que para poder restarle la cantidad_resta a la cantidad_total que ya tengo registrada en base de datos por cada código de producto, tendría que primero hacer una consulta de cada registro y hacer el update de acuerdo a la cantidad que estoy enviando por el archivo excel.

Cualquier guía o ayuda que me puedan brindar me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Comment: La idea que planteas es más o menos correcta. ¿Cuál es tu problema concretamente con respecto al código?

Comment: Hola A. Cedano un gusto. No se de que forma hago el update por cada fila cargada. y/o la consulta primero para comparar la variable de la cantidad.

Comment: El tipo de consulta que necesitas aquí es básico, en cualquier tutorial aparece: `UPDATE laTabla
SET laColumna = laColumna - elValorASustraer WHERE laColumnaAComparar=elValorAComparar` Entonces, arma tu código, intenta hacerlo funcionar y si da errores edita la pregunta indicando qué errores o problemas tienes.

Comment: Entendido, voy hacer eso y ya les cuento como me fue.